# django variable passing

Tags: django, templates

I have a page that I'm rendering with Django call it example.html.  In example.html I have some code that is something like

```
{{ MyObject.Attribute }}
```

How do I get MyObject to be passed into the page so that I can display it? I know that it's in urls.py, but I'm not exactly sure how it works.

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial has a section ...

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something

.. that walks you through it.